# Magento 2 is not reading my requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I am trying to add slick.js to my website. I started by following this tutorial- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-slick-carousel/

I have my slick.min.js here- >app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/js/slick.min.js.

I created a `requirejs-config.js` at `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/`
(after looking at the comments on the tutorial it mentions to move the file to `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/`, so I did all of these steps at both locations.)

I pasted this code in the new requirejs-config.js file-

```
var config = {
   paths: {
    slick:        'js/slick'
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
};
```

I cleaned and flushed the cache, and ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy(I am in developer mode so I do not believe it does anything).

I started researching and came across this answer- [Magento2 not reading my requirejs-config.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95092/magento2-not-reading-my-requirejs-config-js?rq=1)

I deleted the requirejs-config.js here- >pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js

After that, I ran

```
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento cache:flush
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Still can't get that code to show up in require.js. Please advise on what I can try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `requirejs-config.js` should be in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js` and not in `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/requirejs-config.js`
2. Your `requirejs-config.js` should be like this:

   ```
   var config = {
       paths: {
           slick: 'js/slick.min'
       },
       shim: {
           slick: {
               deps: ['jquery']
           }
       }
   };
   ```
3. Remove the content of :

   `var/view_preprocessed`, `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`
4. compile the static contents : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Thank You! I have no idea what did it but that worked.