# 404 / 500 after installing Magento 2.3

Tags: 404, magento2.3

we are trying to **install magento community** on a **Wamp64 server** with PHP 7.1.22 via composer.

1- we made a new folder on the www call store, go to cmd wamp64/www/store and run:

composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
2- wue place everything that was on project-community-edition folder unther the store file

3- open apache httpd-vhosts.conf and place this:

ServerName store
ServerAlias store
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/tuchile"

Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Allow from all

4- open windows host and place 127.0.0.1 store

5- restart the computer

6- open phpmyadmin and create DB store

7- open Chrome on the url store/

8- follow the install procedure

then:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0ClD.png)
[image]

after looking on many pages like:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12828

[Magento2 not reading my requirejs-config.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95092/magento2-not-reading-my-requirejs-config-js)

https://magecomp.com/blog/fixing-failed-to-load-resources-error-after-installing-magento-2/

we did:

1.-

ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*

ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*

ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*

2.-

Php.ini change max_execution_time to 500, memory_limit to 2048M, post_max_size to 2048M, upload_max_filesize to 2048M and max_file_uploads to 2048

3.-

Change

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

To:

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

4.-

Delete everything from ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS

5.- run all this command:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_CL -f
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

and still same error!!!

can anyone please help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3 runs correctly with PHP 7.1.22 (I have installed with PHP 7.1.24)

Magento 2.3 required PHP 7.1.3+, this does mean 7.1.22 is covered

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:
[After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly/252070)

```
Find : /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139

find : 
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}

Replace with:
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's working

Comment: Good!!!!! after 3 days finally go it to work!!!! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

2.10 and still did not work.
after changing:
Find : /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139

find : 
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}

Replace with:
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}

Finally it is working!!