# Magento 2.3.3 - show search bar on mobile version

Tags: magento2

The search bar appears in the mobile version when you press the magnifying glass. I wish the search bar could move under the logo and be active all the time.
Can anyone guide me?

I use Magento 2.3.3 with Codazon Infinit theme.

What is currently there (you need to click the search icon to make the search bar appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `vendor\magento\module-search\view\frontend\web\js\form-mini.js` you have function `setActiveState` in which you have:

```
this.searchForm.toggleClass('active', isActive);
this.searchLabel.toggleClass('active', isActive);
```

which add class to the label and form. If class and form has class `active` they are shown. You have to override this function

**EDIT:**
How to override Js file:
create custom module under `/app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]`. Our `Vendor` name will be `Override` and module name `Js`. So first create file `registration.php` in `app/code/Override/Js`
**app/code/Override/Js/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Override_Js',
    __DIR__
);
```

Then under `app/code/Override/Js/etc` create file `module.xml`.
**app/code/Override/Js/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Override_Js" setup_version="0.0.1">

    </module>
</config>
```

Next step is to create file `requirejs-config.js`
**app/code/Override/Js/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Search/js/form-mini':'Override_Js/js/form-mini'
            }
        }
    };
```

Last thing to do is to creat your Js file. So create :
**app/code/Override/Js/view/frontend/web/js/form-mini.js**
with content from:
`vendor\magento\module-search\view\frontend\web\js\form-mini.js` and make any changes you want.
After this run:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Override_Js
php bin/magento setup:upgrade   
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**TIP:** first put some `alert('test');` in the `_create: function () {` to see if requirejs works. If not follow [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95092/magento2-not-reading-my-requirejs-config-js)

Comment: How can i override this function?

Comment: Please check this link : https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-js-file-in-magento-2/

Comment: Let me know if you did this

Comment: I tried, but I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: did you run setup:upgrade after creating module?

Comment: I tried, but i receive " There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace." so i delete the module. I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Check my updated answer