# Where to locate requirejs-config.js on the home page of my Magento 2 site which uses a custom third party theme?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, frontend-error, requirejs-config.js

I wonder why Network tab in Browser Developers Tool Panel doesn't show requirejs-config.js at the top along with mixins.js, require.js. I am using a custom third party theme. When using Magento Luma theme, I can see all these where I expect them to be. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: can try this :- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer && php bin/magento cache:clean
and link 2> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95092/magento2-not-reading-my-requirejs-config-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none has answered my own question yet when I have found the answer, I feel obliged to answer it. All one has to do is to disable JS Merging for the requirejs-config.js file to appear in the developers tool panel, under the Network tab.